# How to create struct data globally accessible in a singleton class in swift 2.0 (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, singleton

I'm very new to iOS programming and swift. I am trying to create a singleton class to store my global data. My global data are a struct and an array of this struct. I want to have only one instance of this class, thus a singleton class. Global data should be accessible and editable to all ViewControllers. I have been searching around and I almost have it figured out except one last part. Here is the singleton class:

```
    import Foundations
    class Global {

     struct Info {
      var firstname:String!
      var lastname:String!
      var status:String!

      init (firstname:String, lastname:String, status:String)
       {
        self.firstname=firstname
        self.lastname=lastname
        self.status=status
       }
    }

   var testString: String="Test" //for debugging
   var member:[Info]=[]

    class var SharedGlobal:Global
     {
      struct Static 
      {static let instance = Global()}
      return Static.instance
     }
    }
```

Now I want to access the global variables of this singleton class from some viewControllers. When I type this in xcode:

```
    Global.SharedGlobal.
```

I get two options one is the array **member** and the other is the **testString**. The struct Info is not available. However, if I just type

```
    Global.
```

then I see **Global.Info** and **Global.SharedGlobal** as my options.

Why is that I can't access the struct in my singleton class (i.e.  Global.SharedGlobal.Info)? I am missing something? I appreciate any feedback or help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You didn't create any instance of the Info struct.

Comment: So I would do that by writing something like this?:  var StructInfo: Info; and then I can access it through Global.SharedGlobal.StructInfo?

Comment: Let me ask a question first, because it could change the possible answers to your questions: are your classes/structs nested on purpose for a specific reason or is it just happening to be like this and you're not sure about it?

Comment: No reason at all. This is what I found online. I know with the new version of swift it can be done in a different form (maybe simpler) but I couldn't understand how to implement it. I just wanted to make sure that there is only one instance of this class throughout the whole process and that I can modify the variables anywhere. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless there's a very specific reason to do it, you don't need to nest classes like that.

Let's simplify a bit your code for the exercise:

```
struct Info {
    // No need for these properties to be Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals since you initialize all of them
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var status: String

    init (firstname:String, lastname:String, status:String) {
        self.firstname=firstname
        self.lastname=lastname
        self.status=status
    }
}

class Global {

    // Now Global.sharedGlobal is your singleton, no need to use nested or other classes
    static let sharedGlobal = Global()

    var testString: String="Test" //for debugging

    var member:[Info] = []

}


// Use the singleton like this
let singleton = Global.sharedGlobal

// Let's create an instance of the info struct
let infoJane = Info(firstname: "Jane", lastname: "Doe", status: "some status")

// Add the struct instance to your array in the singleton
singleton.member.append(infoJane)
```

Now it would make sense to me. A struct holding info about some user, and I can make any number instances of them - and a singleton class, unique, were I can store these Info instances, this singleton being usable anywhere.

Is it the kind of thing you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I have two questions about your code. Why do I need to add `let singleton = Global.sharedGlobal`? Why can't I just use `Global.shareGlobal.member.append(infoJane)`? The other question is, if I use the key `static` before defining the struct then would that mean I can only have one instance of the struct? just curious to know. Thanks again.

Comment: No, this syntax construction is specific to what makes a singleton, don't try - for now - to replicate it in other contexts. //// A normal class would be instantiated like this: `let object = MyClass()`. But here this is done inside the static var, so when we call `let singleton = Global.sharedGlobal` the first time, `static let sharedGlobal = Global()` is executed, but the next times it will be only accessed, not re-created. So it's a singleton: created only once with `let singleton = Global.sharedGlobal`, and each new `let xxx = Global.sharedGlobal` will only access it, not create new ones.

Comment: Oh ok got it! Thanks so much for the clear explanation. I really had a hard time understanding this. I will try this tonight at home.

Comment: (Eric D.) @AliM Global.sharedGlobal.member.append(infoJane) could be call before let singleton = Global.sharedGlobal  . Global could be also the struct, in that case its static member sharedGlobal must be var not let. the value semantic  'singletone' could have also, as usually, some advantage / disadvantages.

Comment: @user3441734 1: yes. 2: yes. 3: yes. :) I was just trying to keep my example content similar as OP's one, on purpose, to let them focus on the essential part. But your notes are right, of course.

Comment: Great answer. Its totally what i needed.