# How to create a proper singleton for Dictionary in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I have the following code

```
class Test: UIViewController {
  var imagesOfChef = [Int : chefImages]()
    struct chefImages {
          var objidChef: String!
          var imageChef: UIImage!
      }

}
```

I fill up this dictionary as soon as the user opens the application.
But i want it to be available also in other Views (swift files)

Lets say in this class

```
class Test2: UIViewController{

}
```

How can i create a singleton for this Dictionary so it can be available to other views?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Example here with an array, easy to adapt for dictionary: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35440014/2227743 You can also have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36012158/2227743.

Comment: You can try like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38825263/6433023

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a static property:

```
static var imagesOfChef = [Int : chefImages]()
```

and then you use:

```
Test.imagesOfChef
```

But I suggest avoiding the static approaches as much as possible, you can use the prepare segue or assign the property from outside if possible if Test has Test2.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of examples on StackOverlow about how to create a Singleton.

Anyway, your code should be like this

```
struct Chef {
    let id: String
    let image: UIImage
}

final class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private init() { }        
    var dict = [Int: Chef]()
}
```

Now in any source of your app you can use it

```
Singleton.sharedInstance.dict[1] = Chef(id: "1", image: UIImage())
```